# Mongoid: Save an array of strings throws TypeError?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

What am I doing wrong? I have this Mongoid-based model:

```
class ReadableThing
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :shop,    type: Integer
  field :user,                 type: Integer
  field :title,                type: String
  field :s_title,              type: String
  field :s_desc,               type: String
  field :is_part,              type: Boolean
  field :pieces,               type: Array

  def self.with_shop_only(shop, with_parts)
    ReadableThing.where(shop_id: shop, user: nil, is_part: with_parts)
  end

  def self.with_shop_and_user(shop, user_id, with_parts)
    ReadableThing.where(brokerage_shop_id: shop, user: user_id, is_part: with_parts)
  end
end
```

and when running this code:

```
ReadableThing.create({
  shop: 2,
  user: nil,
  title: "Ooohh samples",
  s_title: "SPL",
  s_desc: nil,
  is_part: true,
  pieces: ["this","is","a","sample"],
})
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

I've been able to track the thing down to the "pieces" array, everything works just perfect without it. I can't, though, figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone please lend me a hand here?

Comment: Leaving it without a 'type' doesn't solve anything either.

Comment: Are you able to add items into the `pieces` array after saving a new `ReadableThing`? So for example, after you saved a new `rt = ReadableThing.create({....})` successfully, can you do `rt.pieces = ["this","is","a","sample"]` and `rt.save`? Does that work?

Comment: And does your model have any validations that you aren't showing?

Comment: @MikeSlutsky Doing a separate rt.pieces = ["this","is","a","sample"] works, yes. I'd still like to do it the way I'd do it with ActiveRecord though

Comment: @muistooshort no, not really, no. it seems that when transcribing to SO I missed that. It's corrected, it's still happening, and I'm now also left wondering why would that be a problem anyway.